# Select only child divs, and not "grandchild" divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I have a function that recursively adds more divs to a HTML page upon user interaction. These divs represent objects and the inputs represent these object's  properties. The problem is that these objects are nested inside eachother - the part where I need help in is by selecting only child div's informations. I'll try and illustrate the issue:

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="resource"> //lets call this resource "resource 1"
        <div class="method"> // this method as "method 1"
        <div class="method"> // this method as "method 2"
        <div class="resource"> // this resource as "resource 2"
            <div class="method"> // this method as "method 3"
    <div class="resource">
    <div class="resource">
...
```

We have this div "resource", that inside it can be found either another "resource" or "method". Now, the problem is I have to select *only* child divs in loops. Example:

I'd have to select *only* the methods inside resource 1.

### What i've tried:

1. Selecting it using css selectors:

   `resource1.querySelectorAll(".resource > .method")`

but this returns me all three methods (and I need it to return only the 2 method nested directly beneath it). I believe this happens because this selector searches for all divs "method" beneath "resouce" divs (and as all these nested divs have the same classnames, it cannot tell them apart).

2. Selecting it using html selection. e.g:

   `resource1.getElementsByClassName("method");`

again, I needed it to return me only the methods directly beneath document.getElementsByClassName("resource")[0] (that is equal to resource 1), but instead, it returns me not only the methods directly beneath it, but also all the methods found in resources inside resource 1.

3. Using Jquery:
   Searching for more possible solutions, I've found this Jquery line:

`$('.resource').find('.method').first().siblings('.method').addBack().show()`

but I believe it does not work for my case. For this I made it so all primary resources ("resource" divs that are children to no other "resource") have className = "primaryResource". so that:

```
$('.primaryResource') //returns me all the primary resource divs. This works as intended.
$('.primaryResource')[0] //then returns me the first primary div, but
$('.primaryResource')[0].find('.method') or $('.primaryResource')[0].find('.resource') // does 
not return me anyhting, instead it catches Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].find is not a function
```

Comment: I'm not clear on which elements you want to select

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for responding. It's not really a specific one, if I'm looking at "resource 1" I want to select  "method 1" and "method 2", if I'm looking at "resource 2" I want to select "method 3". Sorry for not being clear

Comment: Well then it depends on what you want to select, but wouldn't `.all > .resource > .method` be sufficient to select only the top level and `.all > .resource > .method > .resource > .method` sufficient to only select level 2?

Comment: @MartinStrotbek how do you know which `.resource` element should be searched? Or are all of them being search in one go?

Comment: @j08691 I see where this is going. I believe it does indeed work, but as these divs are recursively created, i'll have to recursively select these levels aswell. I do this using a recursive function:
 
 
`function getResourceElements(resource)
 
 
myFunctionThatGetsInfoINeed()
 
 
for each resource.querySelectorAll(".resource > .method")
 
 
getMethodElements(resource.querySelectorAll(".resource > .method")[index])
 
 
for each resource.querySelectorAll(".resource > .resource")
 
 
getResourceElements(resource.querySelectorAll(".resource > .resource")[index])`

Comment: How would I implement this new query? Because instead of just passing the previous query result as a parameter to the recursive function, I'd need it to construct a new query everytime. Formatting either sucks for waht I tried to do or I couldn't use it properly on my comment above, sorry

Comment: @hungerstar All of them are to be searched eventually, not sure what you mean "in one go" but if I'd have to answer it, yes, I'd caracterize it as "in one go"

Comment: @MartinStrotbek, is the user directly click on a `.resource` element? Are they clicking a single button that's going to parse all the markup inside of `.all`? What are you going to do with all of the `.methods`? Are you creating a list? What is dictating which `.resource` to inspect and return? I guess I'm a bit lost at how/when/where things are going to happen and are connected to one another etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need Jquery object to apply find:

```
$($('.primaryResource')[0]).find('.method')
```

[Run](https://jsfiddle.net/3cm9qptk/)

Answer (score 0):

To enforce only top level div is read...
replace this

```
resource1.querySelectorAll(".resource > .method")
```

with this

```
resource1.querySelectorAll(".all > .resource > .method")
```

[here is a sample fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/bjvx93s8/)

Answer (score 0):

The first selector is really close. You are retrieving all methods that are directly under *any* resource. Of course, you'd like to retrieve all methods under one specific resource.

I'm not sure which resource you want to select, but in the case you want the first one, you can use the following code:

(plain javascript)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.resource:first-child > .method').forEach(function(el) {
  el.classList.add("selected");
});
```

```js
$('.resource:first-child > .method').addClass("selected");
```

(jquery)

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2bpfuge4/1/

```js
(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.resource:first-child > .method').forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.add("selected");
  });
})();
```

```css
.resource,
.method {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.resource {
  background-color: green;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.method {
  background-color: red;
}

.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="resource">
    <div class="method"></div>
    <div class="method"></div>
    <div class="resource">
      <div class="method"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="resource">
    <div class="method"></div>
    <div class="method"></div>
    <div class="resource">
      <div class="method"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You might need to select a different element. You can use :nth-child to select a specific item, or use multiple > selectors to walk the element tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.all > .resource:first-child > .method')
```

This will make sure that the selected `<div>`s are direct children (not grandchildren) of the `<div class="all">` element and only the first resource's methods get selected.

Comment: This didn't work... The code calls these queries recursively, so I have this, basically:
------

```var example = document.querySelectorAll('.all > .resource')[index]
myFunctionThatFetchesInfoINeedFromDivs(example)


function myFunctionThatFetchesInfoINeedFromDivs(example){

example.getInfos
for each (example.querySelectorAll('.resource >  .method'){
 myFunctionThatFetchesInfoINeedFromDivs(example.querySelectorAll('.resource >  .method')[index]);
}
}```

Comment: Could you provide a link to codepen or jsfiddle so I can take a look at what's wrong?

Comment: Hey! I didn't include the WHOLE code, this much code would only enable you to take a look at how I implemented the recursive functions/etc. I'd not be able to show you the whole code because there are multiple classes etc. https://codepen.io/MartinStrotbek/pen/bGGwRLy hope this is enough, if it isn't let me know! thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have time know, maybe tomorrow I'll take a look

Comment: @MartinStrotbek then please try to create a minimal example.

Comment: @MartinStrotbek Please make a working script with only the things that are necessary, because we won't just guess what is happening